# Preserve database information on app delete and reinstall in ios

Tags: ios, keychain

We are building an expense manager app. I want to preserver some data on un-installing and installing the app.Is there any way to preserve the data?
Can I  use data as password and store in Keychain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, saving in iOS keychain is the recommended way of saving data across reinstalls. But make sure you check the limits on amount of data you can save. A few key value pairs shouldn't be a problem.